# Count total number of lines of a string before/after a pattern match

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a file that I need to count the number of lines of a particular string that appears `[/done]` before a certain pattern match `TAG:` and then to continue and keep on increasing in counting till the next pattern match and so and so on till the end of file.

My file

```
    done
    [/done]
    done
    [/done]
    done
    [/done]
    TAG:asdad.bwewk_stght=213.41808
    done
    [/done]
    done
    [/done]
    done
    [/done]
    TAG:asdad.bwewk_stght=3424.43408
    done
    [/done]
    done
    [/done]
    done
    [/done]
    done
    [/done]
    TAG:asdad.bwewk_stght=45424.43308
```

do note that everything after the `TAG:` portion can be different every time, different in length and in characters however it will always start with `TAG:`

So the end result I am after is

```
    3
    6
    10
```

what I have got so far, I am able to count all lines that the string occurs on perfectly however unable to wrap my head around how to proceed from here to do what i am after.

```
     $count = (get-content out.txt | select-string -pattern "[/done]" -SimpleMatch).length | Write-Host
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read and match lines using regex with a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$index = 0
switch -Regex -File out.txt {
    # if line matches `[/done]`, increase index
    '\[/done\]' { $index++ }
    # if line starts with `TAG:`, output index
    '^TAG:' { $index }
}
```

Comment: Also of note: ```Write-Host``` cmdlet does not take pipeline as per [Microsoft docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2). Segment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.3